# Most efficient method to check if dictionary key exists and process its value if it does

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

```
MyDict = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}
```

I can do this few ways:

```
if 'key1' in MyDict:
       var1 = MyDict['key1']
```

or

```
if MyDict.has_key('key1'):
       var1 = MyDict['key1']
```

or

```
if MyDict['key1']:
    var1=MyDict['key1']
```

or

```
try: 
   var1=MyDict['key1]
except KeyError, e:
   pass
```

or I tried something like this but it does NOT WORK like this in python

```
if v=MyDict.get('key1'):
       var1=v
```

And we cold probably figure out lot more working ways to do that.
Which one is most efficient in terms of computing speed?

Comment: `dict.has_key()` has been deprecated, and is gone in Python 3. Do not use it.

Comment: Your examples are not all the same.  The first two check if the dictionary has a specific key while the third tests the boolean value of that key (and assumes it is there).

Comment: @iCodez but in this case empty value will resolve as False and non empty as True - this also works, assuming I dont use 0, False or None in my values. Correct?

Comment: If `'key1'` is not an item in the dictionary, the first two examples will work fine while the third will raise a `KeyError` exception.

Comment: How often is the key going to be missing? Yes, that matters.

Comment: in this specific case it's more likely to be missing - this will be "overwrite this default values dictionary"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A little benchmark for you (ipython):

```
In [1]: def test_1(d, k):
   ...:     if k in d:
   ...:         var1 = d[k]
   ...:         

In [2]: def test_2(d, k):
   ...:     if d.has_key(k):
   ...:         var1 = d[k]
   ...:         

In [3]: def test_3(d, k):
   ...:     try:
   ...:         var1 = d[k]
   ...:     except KeyError as e:
   ...:         pass
   ...:     

In [4]: def test_4(d, k):
   ...:     if d.get(k):
   ...:         var1 = d[k]
   ...:         

In [5]: my_dict = {'key{}'.format(i): 'value{}'.format(i) for i in range(1000)}

In [6]: key_valid = "key5"

In [7]: key_non_valid = "key"

In [8]: %timeit test_1(my_dict, key_valid)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 172 ns per loop

In [9]: %timeit test_1(my_dict, key_non_valid)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 132 ns per loop

In [10]: %timeit test_2(my_dict, key_valid)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 211 ns per loop

In [11]: %timeit test_2(my_dict, key_non_valid)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 171 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit test_3(my_dict, key_valid)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 151 ns per loop

In [13]: %timeit test_3(my_dict, key_non_valid)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 µs per loop

In [14]: %timeit test_4(my_dict, key_valid)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 246 ns per loop

In [15]: %timeit test_4(my_dict, key_non_valid)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 189 ns per loop
```

Conclusion: construction `key in dict` is generally fastest, outperformed only by `try except` *in case of valid key*, because it doesn't perform `if` operation.

(note however `try except` is significantly *slower for invalid keys*: therefore, since the whole point is you don't know if key is valid, then given an unknown probability of valid vs. invalid, stick with `key in dict`).

Comment: If you can ensure values are truthy. Would `var1 = d.get(k, None); if var1: ...` be faster?

Comment: I would want to point that try: except: has the worst performance if the key is not valid. 1.07 µs > 132 ns. I don't understand the "outperformed" of the answer when the difference is more than 800ns when the key doesn't exist and 20ns in favour of try/except when the key exists.

Comment: @Bechma I just tested this with 60k keys and try except took 1 second whereas k in d took 61 seconds.

Comment: remember, `.has_key` is not in python3.8 or python3.9 (not %100 about older python3's)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you *dont* want `var1` to be defined only if `MyDict["key1"]` is set, the obvious solution is `var1 = MyDict.get("key1", default=some_sentinel_or_default_value)`.

wrt/ performances, it mostly depends on whether you expect "key1" to be in your dict most of the times or not. If the first, a try/except block might be faster, else it will be slower (try/except blocks are cheap to setup but costly when there's an actual exception).

If you really worry that much about performances, I suggest you test the various options *on real-life data* using the `timeit` module.

Comment: Not what I want in this case. I want to touch var1 only if key is present (var1 may be set earlier) Your method would overwrite var1 with default every time the key does not exist

Comment: Use `var1 = MyDict.get("key1", var1)` then.

Answer (score 2):

This one of your methods is very fast:

```
if 'key1' in MyDict:
       var1 = MyDict['key1']
```

Assuming certain conditions on the items in your dictionary and the hashing, this [should be on average O[1]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)