# Python Optimizations for basic CSV file

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, pandas, dataframe

I have a pseudo CSV file (separated instead with pipes); there are two columns, the first column header is location and has no relevance to the problem. The second of the two columns is an identifier (in this case username). The file looks something like this

```
Location | Username 
San Francisco, CA | sam001040
Chicago, IL | tinytom
New York City, NY | coder23
Palo Alto, CA | sam001040
```

As you can notice, sam001040, am seen in two cities (San Francisco & Palo Alto).

I need to assign a unique identification number to the username and create a new similarly formatted table with the new id number. The mappings (username -> id) should be stored to disk. The mappings should be stored, because if in a few days I might need to process another file, so I can reuse the previously stored mappings.

So after the id process the file should look like

```
Location | Username | UniqueID
San Francisco, CA | sam001040 | 0
Chicago, IL | tinytom | 1
New York City, NY | coder23 | 2
Palo Alto, CA | sam001040 | 0
```

A few days later a file like this can come in

```
Location | Username 
Grand Rapids, MI | gowolves
Chicago, IL | ill
Los Angeles, CA | trojans 
Castro Valley, CA | coder23
```

Since there are some new usernames, new identifiers need to be created and one we saw from the last time. So the new file outputted should look like this

```
Location | Username | UniqueID
Grand Rapids, MI | gowolves | 3
Chicago, IL | illini | 4
Los Angeles, CA | trojans | 5
Castro Valley, CA | coder23 | 2
```

Here is a [link to the code](http://pastebin.com/hbqzittp), there are some comments and hopefully the names are helpful, but I can clarify anything.

A couple caveats

1. The file I am manipulating is 1.3gb, approximately 20,000,000 rows with about 30% duplication in usernames (translating to 14,000,000 keys in the dictionary)
2. Currently only have access to my local machine (MBP, 8 gb ram, 512 flash memory)

Additional Info / What I've tried so far

- Initially I used for loops in python, then realized that's not good practice, switched over to pandas dataframes accordingly and used lambdas
- Was writing to another file, then decided to print to console and redirected to another file (using >)
- Tried to process the file as a whole, which always caused something to break and once used up 500 gb of memory (don't know how that happened)
- Broke up the large 1.3 gb file into 50 smaller ones, each one takes ~3 hrs to process
- Tried pickling before, then switched to json to store the dictionary after reading Pickle vs. Json (link in comments)
- I ran a profiler (SnakeViz) and [here are the results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ciigm9bom9u1y6g/Python%20Profile.pdf?dl=0). From my understanding it seems like checking the dictionary for keys is taking up time, but from my understanding after reading another stackoverflow post "in" the generally the fastest ([Most efficient method to check if dictionary key exists and process its value if it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859095/most-efficient-method-to-check-if-dictionary-key-exists-and-process-its-value-if))

Main Question -

Am I doing something completely wrong? I've spent the entire week looking at this and am not sure what more to do. I didn't think it would take on the scope of ~150 hours to process everything.

If anyone has any suggestions or different ideas, please let me know! This is my first post, so if I need to include more info (or remove some) I apologize in advanced and will adjust the post accordingly.

Comment: Pickle vs. Json - https://kovshenin.com/2010/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when checking if a key is in a dictionary, do `k in d`, not `k in d.items()` which is dramatically slower, e.g.

```
In [68]: d = {x:x+1 for x in range(100000)}

In [69]: %timeit (67 in d)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 39.2 ns per loop

In [70]: %timeit (67 in d.items())
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop
```

That alone would make a big difference.  But, I would use a pattern more like this, which should speed things up some more. `.map` looks up the id for existing users, and the `.unique()` gets the set of new usernames (filtering to those not matched in the lookup table).

```
df['UserId'] = df['Username'].map(segment_dict)

new_users = df[pd.isnull(df['UserId'])]['Username'].unique()
for u in new_users:
    segment_dict[u] = unique_ids
    unique_ids += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I just removed the .keys() in my current version and am testing that out now. I understand what's going on in the second block, though I feel since there are so many duplicates in the dataset I will be iterating through the file almost twice (theoretically, shouldn't make a difference since it's still O(1), but I feel every little bit counts, since my machine seems to be overheating every time).

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping the `User -> ID` mapping in CSV for use in `pandas`.

Assuming you have a CSV file mapping known usernames to IDs:

```
$  cat ids.csv
sam001040,0
tinytom,1
coder23,2
```

And a new file `newfile.txt` that you need to process:

```
$  cat newfile.txt
Location | Username
Grand Rapids, MI | gowolves
Chicago, IL | ill
Los Angeles, CA | trojans
Castro Valley, CA | coder23
```

You read in `ids.csv`:

```
ids = pd.read_csv('ids.csv', header=None, index_col=0, names=['Username', 'ID'])
```

and `newfile.txt`:

```
newfile = pd.read_csv('newfile.txt', sep=' \| ', skipinitialspace=True)
# or pd.read_csv('newfile.txt', sep='|'), which is faster, but won't work nice
# when the file has spaces like you show
```

Now you can do:

```
newfile_with_ids = newfile.merge(ids, left_on='Username', right_index=True, how='left')
```

All known IDs are already filled in:

```
            Location  Username  ID
0   Grand Rapids, MI  gowolves NaN
1        Chicago, IL       ill NaN
2    Los Angeles, CA   trojans NaN
3  Castro Valley, CA   coder23   2
```

Now, add new IDs:

```
mask = newfile_with_ids['ID'].isnull()
ids = pd.concat([ids, pd.DataFrame(
         data={'ID': 1 + int(ids.iloc[-1]) + np.arange(mask.sum())},
         index=newfile_with_ids.loc[mask, 'Username'].drop_duplicates())])
```

to get:

```
           ID
Username     
sam001040   0
tinytom     1
coder23     2
gowolves    3
ill         4
trojans     5
```

Then write new IDs to the dataframe:

```
newfile_with_ids.loc[mask, 'ID'] = ids.loc[
         newfile_with_ids.loc[mask, 'Username'], 'ID'].values
```

And finally you have:

```
            Location  Username  ID
3  Castro Valley, CA   coder23   2
0   Grand Rapids, MI  gowolves   3
1        Chicago, IL       ill   4
2    Los Angeles, CA   trojans   5
```

Finally, save the new `ids` back and continue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I definitely think I will try something like this when I already have a dictionary saved to disk