# How to check if JSON have specified data?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I need to check if JSON request have specified field. My request can be:
`{"ip": "8.35.60.229", "blackListCountry" : "Az"}` or simply: `{"ip": "8.35.60.229"}`.

How to check if `blackListCountry` is exists in it?

```
userIP = request.json["ip"]
blackListCountry = request.json["blackListCountry"]
print(blackListCountry)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to check if dictionary key exists and process its value if it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859095/most-efficient-method-to-check-if-dictionary-key-exists-and-process-its-value-if)

Comment: "json" is a text format, not a data type. What you have here is a plain `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = {"ip": "8.35.60.229", "blackListCountry" : "Az"}
if "blackListCountry" in x:
    #key exists
else:
    #key doesn't exists
```

Answer (score 2):

`request.json()` actually return a dict, so you can use the `.get()` method which returns `None` if key is not found:

```
blackListCountry = request.json.get("blackListCountry")

if blackListCountry is None:
    # key is not found
else:
    print(blackListCountry)
```

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way to do this:**

```
x = {"ip": "8.35.60.229", "blackListCountry" : "Az"}
print('blackListCountry' in x)
> True
```

`in` search key 'blackListCountry' and return bool True or False.