# Counting frequencies(efficiently) of strings in a large text file when their pre-counts are given

Tags: python, string

I have a list of lists of the form:

```
[['about70-130 characters long string', '332'], ['someotherrandomstring','2'], ['about70-130 characters long string', 32], ['someotherrandomstring', '3333']]
```

**TO DO:**
I eventually want to sum the sizes of all the repeated strings like so:

```
[['about70-130 characters long string',364], ['someotherrandomstring',3335]]
```

I wrote a brute-force code to solve this but it's taking me a lot of time because the list has about 2 million lists. The very non-efficient code I wrote is:

```
final = {} 
for element in both_list:
    size = int(element[1])
    if element[0] not in final.keys():
       final[element[0]] = size
    else:
       final[element[0]] += size
```

I'm pretty sure there's a more time-efficient code but I can't seem to come up with any ideas. Any help and pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Pytthon 2 or 3?

Comment: You should use `if final.get(element[0]):` not `if element[0] not in final.keys():`. The second one checks the entire list, the first one uses a constant time lookup.

Comment: @maxm That depends on the Python version. In Python3 `keys()` returns a set-like view. Still, just removing `.keys()` is possible.

Comment: Oh cool, good to know

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm using python2

Comment: @prameshshakya Then not using `keys()` is an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay to use third party library pandas

```
import pandas as pd
a=[['about70-130 characters long string', '332'], 
    ['someotherrandomstring','2'],['about70-130 characters long string', 32],['someotherrandomstring', '3333']]
df=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['label','counts'])
df.counts=df.counts.astype('int')
df.groupby('label')['counts'].sum().to_dict()
```

It might be little faster than your solution

```
a=[['about70-130 characters long string', '332'], 
    ['someotherrandomstring','2'],['about70-130 characters long string', 32],['someotherrandomstring', '3333']]
d={}
for i in a:
    if i[0] not in d:
        d[i[0]]=d.get(i[0],int(i[1]))
    else:
        d[i[0]]=d.get(i[0])+int(i[1])
```

Comment: What would be your suggestion to make it run faster without using pandas? That would be really helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: Does the 'if' statement in the second code check the dictionaries keys()? I don't get  how the "if" statement is working.

Comment: @prameshshakya https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859095/most-efficient-method-to-check-if-dictionary-key-exists-and-process-its-value-if

Answer (score -1):

Using `itertools.groupby` with `operator.itemgetter`, or `lambda`

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
res = []

for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0)):
    res.append([k, sum([int(i[1]) for i in list(g)])])
print(res)
# [['about70-130 characters long string', 364], ['someotherrandomstring', 3335]]
```

Comment: How would sorting make this faster?

Comment: @G_M try it without sorting

Comment: Your code breaks without sorting first. You seem to have increased the complexity from `O(n)` to at least `O(n log n)` unnecessarily?

Comment: @G_M if you dont sort the list it wont produce the proper results as when you pass list to groupby the items wont be organized properly to achieve the result

Comment: Sorting increases the complexity of your algorithm and, in this case, it is totally unnecessary. The problem can be solved in a single pass without sorting.

Comment: @G_M not discussing this furter, remove the sorting step and look at the results, they will not be the proper output, cheers

Comment: If you don't understand the problem, how can you think your answer is going to help anyone?

Comment: @G_M okay let me remove the sort and present a output that doesn't match the requested ouput, makes sense, again good day :)

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ You have made this problem go from `O(n)` to `O(n log n)` by your lack of understanding... https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity