# Improve performance of dictionary search in Python

Tags: python, performance

I am using a dictionary structure in python to store (row, col) from a large numpy array.
The length of the dictionary object is almost 100,000

The key is a tuple of (row,col). Some of the sample values in this structure are:

```
OrderedDict([((1783, 586), 0), ((1783, 587), 1), ((1783, 588), 2), ((1783, 589), 3), ((1783, 590), 4), ((1784, 584), 5), ((1784, 585), 6), ((1784, 586), 7), ((1784, 587), 8), ((1784, 588), 9), ((1784, 589), 10), ((1784, 590), 11), ((1784, 591), 12), ((1784, 592), 13), ((1784, 593), 14), ((1784, 594), 15), ((1784, 595), 16), ((1785, 583), 17), ((1785, 584), 18), ((1785, 585), 19), ((1785, 586), 20), ((1785, 587), 21), ((1785, 588), 22), ((1785, 589), 23), ((1785, 590), 24), ((1785, 591), 25), ((1785, 592), 26), ((1785, 593), 27), ((1785, 594), 28), ((1785, 595), 29), ((1785, 596), 30), ((1785, 597), 31),...
```

The processing is taking forever for lookups using the key.

I perform a lookup using (row,col):

```
if (1783,586) in keyed_var_pixels:
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602934/check-if-a-given-key-already-exists-in-a-dictionary) post, using *in* keyword for a dict object should use hashing. 
For each of the lookup, it seems to take around 0.02 seconds, and a total of 30 mins if running for the entire dataset. This seems too long for a hashed retrieval. I am wondering how I can improve this runtime? Or any alternative data structure to store these values for fast retrieval and existence check.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe add a column to the numpy array and store the value there?

Comment: This benchmark information should help you understand better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860508/3218127

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example so we can compare the execution time of each algorithm?

Comment: How often does your `if (...) in keyed_var_pixels` return false? If that is reasonably low, you can simply try an `try except` construct instead of an `if` (following the ask for forgiveness rather than permission principle).

Comment: Can you show the code that takes 30 minutes, not just a single lookup? What are you trying to achieve? Why did you not do this using operations on the original NumPy array, it is supposed to be fast.

Comment: No way that takes 0.02 seconds.

Comment: @NicolasMartinez Thank you. I didn't think about that. I am not too comfortable with numpy, so was going the regular data structure route.

Comment: @rkatkam Thank you, that's helpful.

Comment: I think there must be some issue with my code. When I tried creating a random variable with a tuple and performed a performance test, it improved significantly - in the range of 20-30 microseconds. I will analyze it further and update the question. Thank you very much for your help, @Marcos, coffinjunky, mkrieger1, Heap Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I did a few performance test a while ago and a two level dictionary is faster than using a tuple as key:

```
d = { 1783:{ 586:0, 587:1 ... },  ... }

if 1783 in d and 586 in d[1783] : 
    # ...
```

or you can define an empty default and do it like this:

```
notFound = dict()
# ... 
if 586 in d.get(1783,notFound):
   # ...
```

or this:

```
value = d.get(1783,notFount).get(586,None)
if value is not None:
   # ...
```